# Can you count links within a range?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I have many Google sheets that require manually hyperlinking (to specific unique documents) after other users have inserted values, but it is time-consuming to search through many sheets for cells yet to be linked.  A basic solution would be to use `COUNTA` to get the number of cells within a range containing text, and a second function to count the number of links, showing the difference.  I've tried many permutations of `COUNTA` and `COUNTIF` using wildcards but nothing seems to be able to recognise formulas.  Is there a function within Google Sheets of getting the number of hyperlinked cells within a range?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to urls in cells (like: www.google.com), you can try:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(N(ISURL(A3:A))))
```

Change range to suit.

This will not work if you are using =HYPERLINK() function.

EDIT: If you want to count the cells with text, but exclude the =Hyperlink() formulas (AND empty cells) you can try this custom function:

```
function countF(range) {
var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(range),
    formulas = r.getFormulas(), 
    count = 0;
r.getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        r.forEach(function (c, j) {
            if (c && formulas[i][j].substring(1, 10) !== "HYPERLINK") count += 1;
        })
    })
return count;
```

}
This custom function can be used in your spreadsheet by entering

```
=COUNTCELLS("Sheet1!A1:A2")
```

If you want to exclude all formulas from your count, change the if-statement to:

```
if (c && !formulas[i][j]) count +=1
```

Make sure you always mention the sheet name.

EDIT2: to count the number of formulas, you can try something like this:

```
function countFormulas(range) {
var count = 0;
SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getRange(range).getFormulas()
    .forEach(function(r) {
        r.forEach(function(c) {
            if (c.charAt(0) == '=') count += 1;
        })
    })
return count;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate you putting a reply forward. Unfortunately I can't use that because I am indeed using =HYPERLINK function. Another user puts in a reference number then I later add a link using =HYPERLINK - I'm not aware of another way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this also

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at this also.  I do want to count/include =HYPERLINK but as that will always be the only formula entered just getting a count of formulas in a range would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following. The formula assumes the cells to check for Hyperlinks are in column A with header (adjust formula to your need). Select A2. Right click and select Conditional Formatting. Enter the following:

Apply to range

A2:A

Format cells if

Choose 'Custom formula is' from dropdown list and enter:

=AND(NOT(ISFORMULA(A2)),NOT(ISBLANK(A2)))

Choose the formatting style you want.

This will format and non blank cell not containing a formula. (No Hyperlink)

Two other options to get just a count:

In a column, lets say B enter the following formula(Note that ISFORMULA does not work in array formulas like ISBLANK does.) Copy the formula down. It will return FALSE if there is a Hyperlink and TRUE if there is not.

```
=NOT(ISFORMULA(A2))
```

Then to count use:

```
=countifs(B2:B,"TRUE",B2:B,"<>''")
```

The other option is script:

```
function noFormula() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() 
 var s = ss.getSheets()[0];// [0] is Sheet1
 var lr=s.getLastRow()
 var rng =s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 1) //get column A data. Assumes header row.
 var data=rng.getFormulas()
  count=0
 for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
   var hasFormula=data[i][0]
   var eqSign=hasFormula.substring(0,1) //looks for first character "=". If  there are formulas other than Hyperlinks change to substring(0,2) to look for "=H". 
 if(eqSign !="="){ //Not equal to"="
   count = count+1
  }}
var c=s.getRange(1,2).setValue(count)//Sheet1 B1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, firstly I don't want to conditionally format I want to calculate the number of cells that HAVE text but DONT have link (ie formula), because if I get a count or value I can reference that elsewhere on another sheet; secondly ISFORMULA returns true if the first cell in a range contains a formula, so it doesn't provide a count.

Comment: I have added two options to count to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I'll have a look at that and let you know.  I was thinking it would have to be a script, as a trial I have:used COUNTA to get number of filled cells in a range then ISFORUMLA for each cell individually, getting a total of TRUE for the range and calculating the difference between that and the COUNTA.